# Why don't my LED Christmas Lights change color at the same rate

Tags: led

I purchased 100 LED C7 - Color Changing, Candelabra Base, Christmas bulbs. They screw into regular 120 Volt string cords that I used to have 25-5 watt incandescent bulbs in. When the lights first come on, they are all the same same color but after that, they all change colors at different rates; the same order of color but at different rates. I'm sure these are mass produced with all the same parts produced at the same time. So why the different rate of change?

Comment: I guess they don't talk to each other and have a mind of their own. ;)

Comment: Without a central clock all devices after a while start to drift. The cheaper the device the bigger the drift between the parts. Christmas lights are very, very cheap.

Comment: What are  you using to synchronize them?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  Hi Guy!!  I'm not using anything to synchronize them.... they're just for Christmas. I was just thinking about it last night after a few egg nogs  and a lot of rum since there was no football.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manufacturing tolerances, plain and simple.

Every part is made with a tolerance.  A 100 ohm resistor, 5%, is between 95 ohms and 105 ohms.

Obviously that is affecting the timing of the various lights.

They are built with a simple timer circuit such as a 555, that relies on a resistor and capacitor, and is therefore subject to the manufacturing tolerances of both, as well as itself. They do not pick up the AC heartbeat, because that would add to the cost of the bulb, I guess. And then you wouldn't buy it.

Comment: Even with a crystal they wouldn't stay in sync.  Ironically, there already *is* a consistent timebase distributed to all of them.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Haha, good point.